# Restore Dual Boot of Kali and Windows 10

Tags: windows, multi-boot, kali-linux

I had a working dual boot system of Windows 10 Pro / Kali Linux.  After a memory upgrade I decided to upgrade the Win 10 from 32 bit to 64 bit which requires a clean install of Windows.  I no longer get a dual boot option - Windows starts by default.  My Kali partition is still there and I do not want to reinstall, reconfigure, and reload the security and pentesting apps.  Is there an easy way to restore the dual boot option?

Answer (score 1):

**If you are using a UEFI boot system;**

---

You could try installing reefind. It can be installed from windows and will, most likely, find your kali partition.

The installation page recommends www.easyuefi.com/index-us.html.

The original page;
http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html

---

**If you are using a legacy boot system;**

---

1. Boot the machine using a Live CD.
2. Open a terminal.
3. Find out the name of the internal disk by using fdisk to look up the
   device's size. For example:
4. sudo fdisk -l
5. Install GRUB boot loader onto the proper disk (the example below
   assumes it is /dev/sda):
6. Grub-install --recheck --no-floppy --root-directory=/ /dev/sda

Ref; xernicus on [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126541/how-to-manually-install-boot-loader) post

---

**Finding Boot system**

---

Running msinfo32 will tell you the boot system somewhere on the first page.

Comment: Also look into http://evanpurkhiser.com/rEFInd-minimal/ is you prefer a better looking boot manager.

Answer (score 1):

Now, for you, you have one beautiful options:
For you, just you have to update and upgrade grub,
For it, Just simple go in live O.S (just like from usb)
In it, Open a terminal, and add the Boot Repair PPA

$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update

Install Boot Repair

$ sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair

Update the GRUB 2 configuration file

$ sudo update-grub

Reinstall GRUB 2 to the drive's MBR or equivalent

Install to the drive, not to the partition. Example: sda, not sda1

$ sudo grub-install /dev/sdX

Inspect the GRUB 2 configuration file. The default is /boot/grub/grub.cfg